# Async SQLite python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, python-asyncio, telegram-bot

I write asynchronous telegram bot using the aiogram library. I decided to use SQLite as a database for storing immutable values. How do I implement asynchronous reads from my database?

Comment: The first part of the question is clearly opinion-based, but the second (and more important) part is a useful question and can be answered. Given that the OP is a new contributor, I have elected to answer the question instead of voting to close.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A wrapper for the `sqlite3` module [already exists](https://github.com/jreese/aiosqlite), and you should use it in your async code.

Alternatively, you can turn synchronous calls into asynchronous ones by wrapping them in [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). For example:

```
async def fetchall_async(conn, query):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(
        None, lambda: conn.cursor().execute(query).fetchall())
```

That gives you a coroutine you can call from your async code without worrying that a long-running execution will block the whole event loop:

```
async def some_task():
    ...
    students = await fetchall_async(conn, "select * from students")
```

But it is a much better idea to leave this to a well-tested package.

Comment: Thank you. Can I pass arguments to execute()? execute(query, (arg,)) does not work.

Comment: @dydoser There should be no problem padsing arguments to [`execute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute). What exactly doesn't work when doing so?

Comment: The one mentioned already uses an executor and single threaded at that.  Is there anything closer to the metal using libuv?

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins I don't know - perhaps you should ask a question, preferably with details why existing solutions don't satisfy your requirements.

Comment: The [`databases` package](https://www.encode.io/databases/) also provides this capability for SQLite and a number of other databases. `databases` is more popular than `aiosqlite` (as measured by GitHub stars), but they are both mature and actively maintained.

Comment: PS: Turns out `databases` uses `aiosqlite` as a back-end for SQLite support...